# How to synchronize two calendars from two different Google Apps accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

I have two companies(A, B) , I use Google Apps for both.

Company A and Company B uses same conference rooms for meetings.

If company A books a conference room in its google app calendar, Company B won't know that is booked.

So I want a way to sync these two Calendars without sharing two Calendars publicly.

Answer (score 1):

- For organization a and b put all the members of the organization in a
  group. (You can do this from the admin console)
- Open the Calendar setting and go to sharing.
- Share it with each of the two groups (you may have to add the calendar owner to both groups)